# LibConfig - How to get container list

Tags: c, libconfig

I have the following configuration, I know how to loop through each of the sections with config_lookup(), but I do not know how to find the name of each of the section!

```
downloads = {

    john = {

        configid = 1;
        status = 1;
        configname = "John's File Server";
        configtype = 0;
        ipaddress = "192.168.1.100";
        username = "test";
        password = "test";
    };

    jill = {

        configid = 3;
        status = 1;
        configname = "Jill's file server";
        configtype = 0;
        ipaddress = "10.10.20.50";
        username = "test";
        password = "test";
    };
};
```

I was wondering how to get the section name ie., jack & jill with libconfig. I know how to get the values in jack and jill, because I know the param names beforehand, but jack and jill is user configed. Shortened code goes like this-

```
config_t cfg;
config_setting_t *setting;
int i = 0, count = 0;

if(!config_read_file(&cfg, filename))
    return false;

if((setting = config_lookup(&cfg, "downloads")) != NULL)
{
    count = config_setting_length(setting);

    for(i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

config_destroy(&cfg);
```

Any idea how to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm guessing you need to use the `config_setting_get_elem` function to get an element by an index number, then use the `config_setting_name` function to find out the name of the element. The `config_setting_type` function can be used to find out the element type.

Comment: worked like a charm.. thanks a lot @IanAbbott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so since Ian didnt post an answer, I am. Credit goes to Ian.

```
config_t cfg;
config_setting_t *setting;
int i = 0, count = 0;

if(!config_read_file(&cfg, filename))
    return false;

if((setting = config_lookup(&cfg, "downloads")) != NULL)
{
    count = config_setting_length(setting);

    for(i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        config_setting_t *nodes = config_setting_get_elem(setting, i);
        const char *section_name = = config_setting_name(nodes); // Section name, no need to free, the library manages that;
    }
}

config_destroy(&cfg);
```